# Invalid operation exception when fetching document mongodb c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, bson

My Rider IDE aborts the unit test when I try to fetch a document that was just inserted. I suspect it has to do with the serialization of the string Id to ObjectId. There is no problem inserting the document or replacing it, but it just aborts when using the Find() operation.
This is the mongo context:

```
public class MongoContext : IMongoContext
{
    private IMongoDatabase Database { get; set; }
    public MongoClient MongoClient { get; set; }
    private readonly List<Func<Task>> _commands;
    public IClientSessionHandle Session { get; set; }

    public MongoContext(string connectionString, string database)
    {
        //BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.CSharpLegacy;
        _commands = new List<Func<Task>>();

        RegisterConventions();
        
        MongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        Database = MongoClient.GetDatabase(database);
    }

    private void RegisterConventions()
    {
        var pack = new ConventionPack
    {
        new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true),
        new IgnoreIfDefaultConvention(false)
    };
        ConventionRegistry.Register("My Solution Conventions", pack, t => true);
    }
```

This is the base entity class:

```
[Serializable]
public class MongoEntity
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))] 
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
}
```

And this is the inherited class:

```
[Serializable]
public class HashKmerOrganism:MongoEntity
{
    public HashKmerOrganism() 
    {
        Organisms = new List<string>();
    }
    public HashKmerOrganism(int hash,string kmer):this() 
    { 
        Hash = hash; 
        Kmer = kmer; 
    }
    public HashKmerOrganism(int hash, string kmer, IEnumerable<string> organisms) : this(hash, kmer)
    {
        Organisms = organisms.ToList();
        
    }
    public HashKmerOrganism(int hash, string kmer, string organism) : this(hash, kmer, new[] { organism }) { }
    public int Hash { get; set; }
    public string Kmer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Organisms { get; set; }
    public bool IsKmerReversed { get; set; }
    public double TmApprox { get; set; }
    public int OrganismCount { get => Organisms.Count(); set => OrganismCount = value; }

}
```

These are the repository methods used:

```
public async Task Upsert(HashKmerOrganism hashKmerOrganism)
        {
            var filterList = new List<FilterDefinition<HashKmerOrganism>>();
            var filterBuilder = Builders<HashKmerOrganism>.Filter;
            filterList.Add(filterBuilder.Eq(x => x.Hash, hashKmerOrganism.Hash));
            filterList.Add(filterBuilder.Eq(x => x.Kmer, hashKmerOrganism.Kmer));
            var res = await DbSet.ReplaceOneAsync(filterBuilder.And(filterList), hashKmerOrganism, new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = true });
        }
        public async Task<HashKmerOrganism> GetByKmer(string kmer) => await DbSet.Find(Builders<HashKmerOrganism>.Filter.Eq(x=>x.Kmer,kmer))
            .SingleAsync();
```

This is the unit test that just aborts:

```
[TestClass()]
public class HashKmerRepositoryTests
{
    IHashKmerRepository HashKmerRepo;
    private IMongoContext Context;
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        var databaseName = "Organism";
        Context= new MongoContext(connectionString, databaseName);
        HashKmerRepo = new HashKmerRepository(Context);
        
        
    }
    [TestMethod()]
    public async Task UpsertTest()
    {
        var document = new HashKmerOrganism(1, "kmerstring1", "org1");
        var kmer = document.Kmer;
        var documentToReplace = new HashKmerOrganism(1, "kmerstring1", new List<string> { "org1", "org2" });            
        await HashKmerRepo.Remove(document);
        await HashKmerRepo.Upsert(document);
        await HashKmerRepo.Upsert(documentToReplace);
        var actualDoc = await HashKmerRepo.GetByKmer(kmer);
        Assert.AreEqual(documentToReplace.Organisms, actualDoc.Organisms);
        
    }
```

When I run the unit test, I get no error message whatsoever. It just aborts, and these are the logs:

```
    --- EXCEPTION #1/2 [InvalidOperationException]
Message = “Process was not started by this object, so requested information cannot be determined.”
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException
ClassName = System.InvalidOperationException
HResult = COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION=80131509
Source = System.Diagnostics.Process
StackTraceString = “
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
     at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Processes.PreparedProcessFromRunningProcess.WaitForExitAndSignal()
”

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #2/2 [LoggerException]
Message = “Process was not started by this object, so requested information cannot be determined.”
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
InnerException = “Exception #1 at Root.InnerException”
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = “
  at JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.LogException(ILogger this, LoggingLevel level, Exception exception, ExceptionOrigin exceptionOrigin, String comment)
     at JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.Verbose(ILogger this, Exception exception, ExceptionOrigin origin, String comment)
     at JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.LogExceptionSilently(ILogger thіs, Exception ex)
     at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Processes.PreparedProcessFromRunningProcess.WaitForExitAndSignal()
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
”
```

And this is my debug console output:

```
    /Applications/Rider.app/Contents/lib/ReSharperHost/macos-x64/dotnet/dotnet exec /Applications/Rider.app/Contents/lib/ReSharperHost/JetBrains.Debugger.Worker.exe --mode=client --frontend-port=57544 --plugins=/Applications/Rider.app/Contents/plugins/rider-unity/dotnetDebuggerWorker
Stack overflow.
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the setter of the HashKmerOrganism object. It was causing some recursive operation that was not caught:

```
public int OrganismCount { get => Organisms.Count(); set => OrganismCount = value; }
```

was replaced by

```
[BsonElement]
public int OrganismCount {get => Organisms.Count();}
```